# How do I print the contents of the return register in Assembly? (x86)

Tags: assembly, x86

This is what I am currently doing but `leaq` is not the correct instruction
(I want to print the contents of `%rax` but I need the register for the `syscall` so I move it to `%rdx`) :

```
_printResult:
        movq %rax, %rdx
        movq $1, %rax
        movq $1, %rdi
        leaq %rdx, %rsi
        movq $3, %rdx
        syscall
```

`Error: operand type mismatch for 'lea'`

Comment: What are you trying to do at that `leaq`? `%rdx` itself does not have an address, so taking the effective address of `%rdx` doesn't make sense.

Comment: Copy the contents of `rax` onto the stack (e.g. using a `push` instruction) and pass a pointer to that stack location to the system call.  Note that even if you do this, you'll only print the literal bytes that make up `rax`.  If you want to print the contents as a number, you need to write a conversion routine.

Comment: `lea` requires an addressing mode as the source.  `lea (%rdx), %rsi` would be equivalent to `mov %rdx, %rsi` so is pointless.